# How do i add a cooldown?

Tags: node.js, discord.js, bots

This command is constantly spammed and seems to be breaking the bot

```
bot.on('message', msg=>{
    if(msg.content === "h"){
        msg.channel.send('hㅤ');
    }
 })
```

Again, how would I add a cooldown for this command? I am using discord.js, and I am unsure how I would add any cooldown.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did this:

```js
var usersInTimeout = [];

bot.on('message', msg => {
    if(msg.content === "h"){
        var timeoutDelay = 1000 * 60 * 60;//the cool down you want in ms

        if(usersInTimeout.some(user => user.userID == message.author.id)){//check if the user is in timeout
          var userInTimeout = usersInTimeout.find(user => user.userID == message.author.id);
          var remainingTime = millisec(timeoutDelay - (new Date().getTime() - userInTimeout.timeoutStart)).format('hh:mm:ss');
          return message.reply(`Time left to use the command: **${remainingTime}**`);
        }

        //run the command:
        msg.channel.send('hㅤ');

        usersInTimeout.push({userID: message.author.id, timeoutStart: new Date().getTime()});//add the user to timeout

        setTimeout(() => {//add a timer to remove him from the timeout
          usersInTimeout.splice(usersInTimeout.indexOf(message.author.id), 1);
        }, timeoutDelay);
    }
 });
```

**Explanation:**
Create an array of the users in timeout and whenever the command is fired, check if the user is in that array, if he is then the command will work and the user will be added to the `usersInTimeout` array and won't be able to use the command until he will be removed from it which is after the `timeoutDelay` delay is complete.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a cooldown function in your bot by using [Sets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).

```
const cooldown = new Set();

// Add user to a set and remove them after 5 seconds
cooldown.add(<Message>.author.id);
setTimeout(() => {
   cooldown.delete(<Message>.author.id);
}, 5000);

// Check if user is in the set (i.e. shouldn't be able to use command)
if (cooldown.has(<Message>.author.id)) {
   // Don't let user use the command
} else {
   // Do any logic here and send a message
}
```

So to integrate this into your code, for example:

```
const cooldown = new Set();

// As a function, it can now be called multiple times
// but if you're adding users to the same set then it will stop them from using other commands too
function addToCooldown(ID) {
    cooldown.add(ID);
    setTimeout(() => {
        cooldown.delete(ID);
    }, 5000 /* 5 seconds */);
}

bot.on('message', msg=>{
    if(msg.content === "h"){
        // Send a message if the user is not in the cooldown set
        if (!cooldown.has(msg.author.id)) {
            addToCooldown(msg.author.id);
            msg.channel.send('h');
        }
    }
});
```